# That was just what it was like

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This is an excerpt from [a fiction story](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/01/17/fireworks).

> And the truth was that if, back then, he could have been, in some
> impossible way, both there and not there, just a safe, immune
> spectator, he might have been able to say that, on a grand and
> terrible scale, **that was just what it was like**: immense fires
> below, and up in the sky a great show—flashes and bangs, colored
> flares, dancing searchlight beams.

I wonder what the sentence in bold means here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means he might have been able to say back then - during the war - that a bombing mission **looked exactly like** Bonfire Night.

It doesn't tell us *to whom* he might have been able to say it, but I think it means himself: "the same voice he’d heard inside him when he was a bomb aimer".

There is a suggestion that the comparison eases his distressing memories today.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @StackExchanger: You're welcome. And thanks for the story. It's really good.